# Ruby Second Smallest Number and index

Tags: ruby

Trying to use Ruby to find the second smallest number and the index from an input. I have the logic working from a hard coded array but can't seem to get the input from a user to work successfully. Thoughts?

```
print "Enter a list of numbers: "
nums = [gets]

#nums = [3,1,7,5]
lists = nums.sort
A = lists[1]
B = nums.find_index(A)

print "The second smallest number is: #{A} and the index is #{B}"
```

Comment: The question should be how to get multiple numbers from a user or something like that, not how to access the second element since that's not the issue here

Comment: Variable names starting with a capital letter are constants in Ruby. I don't think that's what you wanted here.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help with parsing the user's input, but what will you do if you have identical values? What should the index return on an input of `3, 1, 7, 5, 5, 1, 3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Scan Input Strings and Map to Integers

The [Kernel#gets](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) method returns a String, so you have to parse and sanitize the user input to convert it to an Array. For example:

```
nums = gets.scan(/\d+/).map &:to_i
```

This uses [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-scan) to parse the input string, and [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-map) to feed each element of the resulting array to [String#to_i](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-to_i). The return value of this method chain will be an Array, which is then assigned to your *nums* variable.

### Results of Example Data

Given input with inconsistent spacing or numbers of digits like:

```
1,2, 3,  4,     5, 10, 201
```

the method chain will nevertheless assign sensible values to *nums*. For example, the input above yields:

```
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 201]
```

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the user entered

```
str = " 2, -3 , 4,   1\n"
```

Then

```
arr = str.split(/ *, */).map(&:to_i)
  #=> [2, -3, 4, 1]
```

The regular expression matches zero or more spaces followed by a comma followed by zero or more spaces.

The second smallest element, together with its index, can be obtained as follows.

```
n, i = arr.each_with_index.min(2).last
  #=> [1, 3]
n #=> 1
i #=> 3
```

See [Enumerable#min](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-min).

The steps are as follows.

```
enum = arr.each_with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: [2, -3, 4, 1]:each_with_index>
```

We can see the elements that will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array.

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[2, 0], [-3, 1], [4, 2], [1, 3]]
```

Continuing,

```
a = enum.min(2)
  #=> [[-3, 1], [1, 3]]
```

`min(2)` returns the two smallest elements generated by `enum`. `min` compares each pair of elements with the method [Array#<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E). (See especially the third paragraph of the doc.) For example,

```
[2, 0] <=> [-3, 1]
  #=> 1
[4, 2] <=> [1, 3]
  #=> 1
[1, 3] <=> [1, 4]
  #=> -1
```

`min` would therefore order these pairs as follows.

```
[2, 0] > [-3, 1]
[4, 2] > [1, 3]
[1, 3] < [1, 4]
```

I've included the last example (though `enum.to_a` does not contain a second `1` at index 4) to illustrate that the second element of each two-element array serves as a *tie-breaker*.

As we want the second-smallest element of `arr` there is one final step.

```
n, i = a.last
  #=> [1, 3]
n #=> 1 
i #=> 3
```

Note that

```
n, i = [3, 2, 4, 2].each_with_index.min(2).last
  #=> [2, 3]
n #=> 2
```

If we wanted `n` to equal `3` in this case we could write

```
n, i = [3, 2, 4, 2].uniq.each_with_index.min(2).last
  #=> [3, 0]
n #=> 3
```

If the entries were floats or a mix of floats and integers we need only replace `to_i` with `to_f`.

```
str = "6.3, -1, 2.4, 3\n"
arr = str.split(/ *, */).map(&:to_f)
  #=> [6.3, -1.0, 2.4, 3.0] 
n, i = arr.each_with_index.min(2).last
  #=> [2.4, 2]
n #=> 2.4
i #=> 2
```